# How to record a Java Web Start Application using Rational Functional Tester

Tags: java, automated-tests, rft

We are trying to register some navigation to a Java Web Start application (`.jnlp`). Following the instructions reported in the last post of [this discussion](http://www.sqaforums.com/showflat.php?Cat=0&Number=648116&Main=645856), we were able to configure properly the application to start using the *Application Configuration Tool*.

After executing the record session, using *Insert Recording into Active Functional Test Script* button, the recorder does not react to any of our actions (i.e. click a button, select a combo, focus on a text area, and so on...).

Is there some plugin to install inside the RFT Studio to enable Java Application recording? Clearly, we are missing something: could someone link us a tutorial or some other equivalent resource?

We are using IBM Rational Functional Tester ver. 8.2.1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the  jre being used by jnlp application should be enabled for RFT to be able to recognize the controls. If JRE is enabled  then it does not really matter if the application is jnlp or standalone.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. We have noticed this yesterday afternoon. But the problem is that RFT lets you record only a _java_ application. If you want to execute a jnlp file using the command `java`, you have to use a quite complex command line. This does not solve the problem, 'cause it seems that IBM JVM is not so good to execute jnlp application. We currently open a support request to IBM.

Comment: You don't need to launch the jnlp with IBM java or  using the java command . No matter how you launch  your webstart application  if the JRE that is used by the application  has been enabled RFT will be able to recognized the controls  correctly.   As per my understanding  when you launch  JNLP file  .. it will either  download a jre of its own  or will use the jre  that is currently installed. You need to identify   which one is the case  and make sure that  "that"  JRE is enabled. IBM jre is not a system jre so it cannot be used to launch applets/jnlp file.

Comment: Using your suggestion we have resolved. We used the RFT JVM and a dos script running the *jnlp* file using the `javaws` command.